# Looking for IF statement with in HTML where a JOIN value true display JOIN NOW Button

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

IF JOIN field value is TRUE then display JOIN NOW  Button

Below is the HTML:

```
<a href="%%=Concat('https://','google.com')=%%" class="button button--secondary" style="background-color: #25861E; border-radius: 999px; color: #FFFFFF; display: inline-block; font-family: arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 48px; padding: 0 35px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase;">
**JOIN NOW**
<span class="button__icon">&nbsp;›
</span>
</a>
```

Not sure how to use the Ampscript with in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the join field is in your sendable data extension, (otherwise you will need to look it up)

```
    %%[IF join == True THEN]%%
       HTML for JOIN now button
    %%[ENDIF]%%
```

You basically write your ampscript code then close it, add any HTML, followed by  additional ampscript logic/close statements.

Comment: Thanks @Noor. I will give a try and see how this goes